# combining list elements of different dimensions

Tags: r

I have a list. It contains 20 elements. First element have 630 columns rest have 3530 columns. The 3530 columns contains 630 columns. Each element have 12 rows. I want to combine this list in a manner that first element contain 3530 columns (630 columns with data rest with NA). I used ldply. But after first 12 observations it fills missing data everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the incomplete data (columns) are present only in 1st element of the list we can work only on that. Assuming your list is called is `list_df`, try

```
list_df[[1]][setdiff(names(list_df[[2]]), names(list_df[[1]]))] <- NA
```

For example, on this data

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 3:7)
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 3:7, c = 13:17, d = 16:20)
df3 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 3:7, c = 13:17, d = 16:20)
list_df <- list(df1, df2, df3)

list_df[[1]][setdiff(names(list_df[[2]]), names(list_df[[1]]))] <- NA

list_df
#[[1]]
#  a b  c  d
#1 1 3 NA NA
#2 2 4 NA NA
#3 3 5 NA NA
#4 4 6 NA NA
#5 5 7 NA NA

#[[2]]
#  a b  c  d
#1 1 3 13 16
#2 2 4 14 17
#3 3 5 15 18
#4 4 6 16 19
#5 5 7 17 20

#[[3]]
#  a b  c  d
#1 1 3 13 16
#2 2 4 14 17
#3 3 5 15 18
#4 4 6 16 19
#5 5 7 17 20
```

If you want then you can combine the data together in one dataframe by doing

```
do.call(rbind, list_df)
```

---

If you use `dplyr` `bind_rows` it would automatically add `NA` to columns which are absent.

```
dplyr::bind_rows(list_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution using a Reduce function to apply a full outer join over all elements in the list:

```
df <- Reduce(function(x, y){

  merge(x, y, by = intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y)), all = TRUE)},

  df_list)
```